# A positive integer $n$ such that $S(n) = 1996\cdot S(3n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> [Ireland 1996] Find a positive integer $n$ such that $S(n) =
> 1996\cdot S(3n)$, where $S$ stands for the sum of digits.

The book "104 Number theory problems" gives the following solution:

Consider the number $n=1333....335$, where there are $5986$ $3$'s in between the first and last digit. Then they proceed to explain how this number satisfies the given conditions. That much is clear enough. Here is my query:

What should have instigated us to look at this type of number? The conditions of the problem gives this question a very foreboding appearance. I can't seem to find any motivation for considering such a number.

Some help in understanding the motivation behind the solution will be appreciated.

Comment: You want $3n$ to have mostly zeroes, to make $S(3n)$ significantly smaller than $S(n)$.  Having a lot of 3's gives you that.

Comment: @vadim123, I am following your reasoning.Since we want more $0$'s,and since we are multiplying $n$ by $3$, a lot of $3$'s in between surely would help.Next we need to make sure of the $1996$ factor.How do we take care of that?

Comment: The first thing I would try is $333\cdots 333a$.  There are now two parameters: how many 3's, and what digit $a$ is.  I would compute $S(n)$, $S(3n)$, and see if I can tweak those parameters to get the desired condition.  I imagine that this won't work, so we need to add additional digits, like $333\cdots 33ab$ or $b333\cdots 33a$.

Comment: @vadim123, I guess a little bit of experimentation with both forms will lead us to the answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as Vadim says, to keep $S(3n)$ small, you can make sure $3n$ contains several zeroes.  Also, since $n\equiv S(n)\pmod9$, we have $1996S(3n)\equiv1996(3n)\equiv3n\pmod9$.  If $S(n)\equiv n\equiv3n\pmod9$, we must have $S(n)\equiv n\equiv0\pmod9$.  So if done right, we can fix $S(3n)$ and add enough filler in the middle to increase $S(n)$.

As possible answers, we have $1$ and $5$ with $5986$ $3$'s in the middle, $2$ and $4$ with $5986$ $3$'s or $4$ and $8$ with $2992$ $6$'s.  In all $3$ of these cases, $S(3n)=9$, so we calculate how much filler is necessary to obtain $S(n)=1996\times9$.

Comment: Nice. Btw, are there an infinite number of such $n$ ?

Comment: @rah4927 I just woke up, but isn't it enough to add zeroes at the end of a solution or between the first and the second digit to get more solutions?

Comment: @Alessandro, yes, one can definitely get more solutions by adding $0$'s at the end or in between the first and second digit. Thanks for that.